# RSOP does not show Local Security Policy

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I just recently removed a 2008 R2 Server from a domain and it will be running as a non-domain member.

I am making changes to the Local Security policy and I noticed that when I run my gpresult and RSOP that they do not display the new settings.

How can I force RSOP to read these settings?

Answer (score 3):

When working with local policies one uses the [Security Configuration and Analysis](https://www.petri.com/using-windows-server-2012-security-configuration-and-analysis-tool) tool to baseline policies.

[By design](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/67c8d598-f61d-449a-a12b-a89a42251192/local-security-policies-do-no-show-up-in-rsop) the RSOP tool cannot access local policies:

> RSOP gathers policies data from a Common Information Model Object
> Management (CIMOM) database on the local computer.
>
> Local Group Policy was not stored in this database and cannot be
> queried by RSOP. Gpedit.msc and secpol.msc just edits system settings
> directly.

Comment: But why does RSOP not show what is really configured in Local Security Policy?

Comment: The reason I ask that because a tool that I used to track baselines and security configurations uses the Local RSOP settings to read the settings

Comment: Added info to the answer.